# Is it possible that `shared_ptr::use_count() == 0` and `shared_ptr::get() != nullptr`?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr, lifetime

From the [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool):

> **Notes**
>
> An empty shared_ptr (where use_count() == 0) may store a
> non-null pointer accessible by get(), e.g. if it were created using
> the aliasing constructor.

Is it possible that `shared_ptr::use_count() == 0` and `shared_ptr::get() != nullptr`?

**Any example to illustrate that is true?**

Comment: Your quote literally answers your question...

Comment: Have you tried using the aliasing constructor (#8 in the list of constructors)?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/s14jdPYx5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the notes, the aliasing constructor causes this to happen.

For example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<float> b(a, new float(0.0));
    std::cout << b.use_count() << "\n";
    std::cout << (b.get() == nullptr) << "\n";
}
```

[prints](https://godbolt.org/z/s14jdPYx5) `0` for the `use_count()` and `b.get()` is non-null.

Note that the `float` isn't managed by the lifetime of `b` and is leaked.

Comment: Worth adding: the reason the float is leaked is because the aliasing constructor is *supposed* to be passed a pointer to some subobject of the object owned by the first `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @o11c not true, the pointer is not required or even expected to be a subobject of the referred shared_ptr. It is simply a raw pointer for `get()` to return, it can be anything the caller wants it to be. What is important is that the pointer is NOT managed or destroyed by the new shared_ptr at all. Only that the new shared_ptr shares ownership of the referred shared_ptr.